# Best way to debug and edit third party library in java?

Tags: java

In javascript, python, golang or rust usually you have the third party source code available in your development environment such that you can edit it and debug it.

I am a beginner in java.

What is the best recommended work flow to debug third party library?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using any kind of package management, instruct it to download the source jar along with the binary jars. Your IDE should then be able to use the downloaded source to debug the library.

Using this method, you aren't really able to modify the library, but you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: There are good reasons to modify external libs: they might be abandoned (and you don't want to clone all of their code), there might be some important change in your environment and the lib developers are too slow for your requirements, ... In npm, you have the option to patch external libs via npmjs.com/package/patch-package during post-install and this is one of the reasons why I enjoy working with JS/TS so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, you should try the Enhanced Class Decompiler, which can be installed by doing Help>Eclipse Marketplace> and then look for "Enhanced Class Decompiler".

You can then debug your app, and while stepping into the third party code, it will decompile bytecode back to Java language and show it into the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If absolutely necessary you can modify the library, by various techniques:

1. extending a non-final class and creating an instance of that instead of the original class. This only works when your application controls the relevant points at which the instances are created. But this is actually the most risky approach, due to various problems around the fragility of implementation inheritance. I would not recommend this approach except for the simplest of needs.
2. copying and pasting some source code from the library into your code and modifying it. Be sure to abide by all the relevant requirements in the license if you do this.
3. checking out the original source code (e.g. from GitHub), tweaking it, rebuilding it and publishing the modified version to your corporate Maven repository under a modified organisation (`com.your.company`) and/or version. Then tweak your dependency specifications to use this modified jar instead of the original.